# Unable to run the pods in AKS with non root user

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, privileges

I was deploying the docker images with root priviliages in AKS, then while running sonar tests, it was complaining about that. I am trying to run the pods without the root user but while the pods are failing in that scenario. I am not sure, it it needs extra privileage. I am creating the non root user in docker file, I have also seen we can set the Security Context in deployment.yaml file in AKS. so, should I try that or do I have to add extra privilieages while adding the user in docker file.

The pods needs to access the config map which is part of volume mount

Here is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WK.CO.Test.API/WK.CO.Test.API.csproj", "WK.CO.Test.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WK.CO.Test.API/WK.CO.Test.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WK.CO.Test.API"
RUN dotnet build "WK.CO.Test.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WK.CO.Test.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
# Create a group and user
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup
# Run as appuser user
USER appuser
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WK.CO.Test.API.dll"]
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/PrakashRajanSakthivel/175b0b683112db36d5830d760fd29aef) is the AKS deployment File

**Update, added error details. pods are in failed state

```
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: containerd://77b18f19cc635d405c59c5d63baae8e4f745a91e8074217ed8334b0fd3d48387
    image: test.azurecr.io/testsvc:1.0.0
    imageID: test.azurecr.io/testsvc@sha256:07c0399a40e7c76590f44a5b34f35305d32024e66b32b851b829819ac0060058
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: containerd://77b18f19cc635d405c59c5d63baae8e4f745a91e8074217ed8334b0fd3d48387
        exitCode: 137
        finishedAt: "2023-04-05T05:48:28Z"
        reason: Error
        startedAt: "2023-04-05T05:48:28Z"
    name: testapi
    ready: false
    restartCount: 3
    started: false
    state:
      waiting:
        message: back-off 40s restarting failed container=testapi pod=testservice-deployment-6fd454bcc4-gzqbh_testservices-test(c38c1cf0-6fa7-44bd-b550-532d019b2d97)
        reason: CrashLoopBackOff
```

Comment: updated the error details.

Comment: perhaps share `kubectl describe pod %name%` and logs from inside the pod if it ever starts?

Comment: no, the pod isnt started. Error from server (NotFound): pods "testservice-deployment-6fd454bcc4-k6f5r" not found

Comment: `kubectl get events`?

Comment: unable to get much info, her is the gist https://gist.github.com/PrakashRajanSakthivel/c83fa63ac2ac29ac5bba9d95d04772f3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this. I have reverted all the security context settings from the AKS deployment.yaml file. and I have updated docker file to open port other than greater than 1024. so, I opened 8080 and also made sure the container listesn to the port. Here is the updated docker file.after deployment, if I open the pod in the terminal and check the id, it has some random ID other than 0 (which is root)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine AS base
RUN apk update
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Release"
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
COPY ["WK.CO.Test.API/WK.CO.Test.API.csproj", "WK.CO.Test.API/"]
COPY ./nuget.config ./
RUN dotnet restore "WK.CO.Test.API/WK.CO.Test.API.csproj"
RUN rm ./nuget.config
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WK.CO.Test.API"
RUN dotnet build "WK.CO.Test.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WK.CO.Test.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
# Create a group and user
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup
# Run as appuser user
USER appuser
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WK.CO.Test.API.dll"]
```